# GitLab to GitHub / Bitbucket mirroring

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, gitlab, githooks

I want to mirror a repository from GitLab to GitHub without duplicating it.

So I want a read-only mirror existing in GitHub that automatically updates from my work in my 'origin' GitLab repository hosted on GitLab.com

How would I go about setting this up and keeping it in sync?

To further add to this, how would I also add another mirror on Bitbucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add multiple remote using `git remote add your-github-url`, and write a crontab to push everything into GitHub from GitLab once a day.

Repeat the same for Bitbucket.